# How to fake my death in 1994

Tags: survival, death, organizations, escape

The year is 1994. I am being monitored by a shadow organization with agents in every corner of the government, public service, and positions of power. Fortunately for me they have a lot of people to monitor so they largely rely on data that they glean from large databases (DMV records, deeds to property, credit card purchases, bank withdrawls, etc...), supplemented by records submitted by their field agents-- only sending out special investigators when something unexpected happens (e.g., a person dies in a freak accident).

My question is how do a fake my death so as to escape their scrutiny? They have the advantage of time, so any clues I leave behind (dental records, DNA, etc...) will remain for examination in the future, and they will eventually realize that I have slipped out from their surveillance. If I do manage to fake my death convincingly, how long would I have be before the dawn of the internet, CCTV, and the ubiquity of facial recognition devices allow them to pin me down again?

Comment: Hehe, in 1994, you *could* hire a hacker, to arrange database changes.. but I wonder, how is this question NOT story-based ?

Comment: VTC:Needs Details. As @Goodies mentioned, you're basically asking us to explain a plot element of your story and not a rule of your world. We will accept questions like this, but you must ask it in a way that's 100% independent of your story. Basically, that means you need to explain the story elements surrounding the circumstance so what's left is objective. As written, you're just fishing for ideas and any idea will work. Remember, the [help] says you shouldn't ask questions where every answer has equal value. (\*Continued\*)

Comment: It looks like your world is already built and you're asking about the actions of a specific individual in your *already built* world. Such question are off topic on this site.

Comment: So, how will you judge a best answer? What limits and conditions must we work with? How will you judge the difference between "A boating accident in the Atlantic" from "Burned to death in a house?" Somehow we need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609).

Comment: I wonder what happens if this question is parachuted on SE/Retrocomputing https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There are two questions here.  The first is "how to fake my death?", the second is "how long before the Illuminati realise I'm alive?".  Pick one, and narrow it down sufficiently - at the very least this requires specifying country of residence, age, profession and available resources (financial and otherwise).  Think about the right question - if you are writing a story, do you really want to know "How long can I stay undetected?" or is it more useful to know something like "which country would let me remain safely 'dead' until 2015?"

Comment: An organization so pervasive and enormous cannot also be "shadow." That many people simply cannot keep a secret.

Comment: How many co-conspirators are you willing to engage? Your dentist and doctor records being faked for example.  And, can you get a body in a way your ethical makeup will accept?

Answer (score 3):

## Sailing

Go on a boat for a long trip. Sailing boats most preferred. Go to a storm or something and rig the emergency beacon to go off easily/after a set time. Have the boat sail into the storm and be picked up by a different boat yourself.

A storm isn't needed. Deep ocean neither. Best is to have the boat or emergency raft discovered with the beacon. As they're empty it is easily assumed that you went overboard and perished. Smugglers and such can help with the details to stay undetected while being picked up. Either by fast boats or submarines. If they catch you being taken from the boat, stage it as a kidnapping for money. An area known for piracy is also good.

Leave some of your own blood behind the boat as if you were injured, leaving DNA traces as well. This can be tapped directly on the boat. Half a liter is normal when giving blood and will look like you're bleeding out to investigators. Just put some effort in blood splatter analysis and how to apply it just in case, but a boat in rough seas can quickly dissolve most evidence except a bloody DNA trail.

If you don't do anything too obvious it should be fine. It'll seem like an enthusiast that went too far and got killed when taking on a storm, or just had an unhappy accident. Though some might still find it a mystery, level headed people will draw the normally right conclusion. Your body is on the bottom of the sea, dragged away by the ocean currents.

All the technology in the world is still not enough to track down so many people in the western world. Go anywhere where technology isn't and it'll help your case even further.

Answer (score 1):

[List of people who disappeared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_people_who_disappeared), with separate sublists for fugitives from justice and people who disappeared mysteriously in various historical periods.

See also [missing person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_person). The most interesting piece of information is that the US [NCIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Crime_Information_Center) database records about 700,000 missing persons per year, of which about 130,000 are adults. In Australia, one person is reported missing every 18 minutes, for a total of about 38,000 per year (which tallies with the American incindece data).

The Wikipedia article also has a list of reasons why people go missing:

> - To escape domestic abuse.
> - Leaving home to live somewhere else under a new identity.
> - Becoming the victim of kidnapping.
> - Child abduction by a non-custodial parent or other relative.
> - Seizure by the authorities (Military, law enforcement, government) and imprisoned / detained indefinitely in an undisclosed location without due process of law (see forced disappearance).
> - Suicide in a remote location or under an assumed name (generally to spare their families the suicide at home or to allow their deaths to be eventually declared in absentia).
> - Victim of murder (body disguised, destroyed, or hidden).
> - Mental illness or other ailments such as Alzheimer's disease can cause people to forget where or who they are.
> - Death by natural causes (disease) or accident far from home without identification.
> - Becoming lost accidentally in remote areas, including when participating in outdoor recreation or labour (hiking, mountaineering, hunting, etc.)
> - Disappearance to take advantage of better employment or living conditions elsewhere.
> - Sold into slavery, serfdom, sexual servitude, or other unfree labor.
> - To avoid discovery of a crime or apprehension by law-enforcement authorities. (See also failure to appear.)
> - Joining a cult or other religious organization that requires no contact to the outside world.
> - To avoid war or persecution during a genocide.
> - To escape famine or natural disaster.
> - Death by floods, flash floods, debris flows, hurricanes, tsunamis and tornadoes.
> - Death in the water, with no body recovered.
> - Aviation accident where no wreckage is found or ship wreck where no wreckage is found